# C# get a tcp packet data as is

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, arrays, networkstream

Is there any way to receive a tcp packet as it was sent?
Like if i send the following byte array: `new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4}`
I want to receive it as a byte array and not in a network stream

Comment: What have you tried so far? Its easier to give a solution suitable for you based on what you already tried.

Comment: You have to use the `NetworkStream` and read the `byte[]` from it

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a streaming protocol. There are no packets. You cannot receive data in the same chunks that you sent them in.

You need to establish some kind of protocol that allows you to read just the right number of bytes. For example, prefix each message with its length.

Better yet, do not use sockets at all. Use something higher level such as WCF or HTTP.